# Why do people think Ezekiel speaks to someone OTHER than Satan/Lucifer in Ezekiel 28:12-14?

Tags: ezekiel

The king of Tyrus was such an important,influential,wicked and powerful figure in the ancient world that when he was possessed,it wasn't by some run-of-the-mill demon out of Hell,but by SATAN himself,so when sending a message TO him through His prophet wouldn't God remind him of where he once dwelt?!?

Comment: I think you have answered your own question!

Comment: Christianity (re)interprets the Old Covenant; compare, for instance, Matthew 2:15 with Hosea 11:1; something similar is going on with Ezekiel 28:12-14.

Answer (score 1):

If you read in context, he has to be talking to the King of Tyre. If he was talking to Satan, why would Ezekiel leave out such a critical detail? The exact words are "בֶּן־אָדָ֕ם שָׂ֥א קִינָ֖ה עַל־מֶ֣לֶךְ צ֑וֹר וְאָמַ֣רְתָּ לּ֗וֹ" or "Mortal, place a dirge on the King of Tyre and you shall say to him" (Ezekiel 28:12). The reading of this as talking to Satan is an eisegesis applying a concept from the Christian bible to the Hebrew Bible. In the Hebrew Bible, Satan is merely a servant of G-d. For example, read in the book of Job and see how Satan does exactly what G-d tells him to do. Satan is merely the chief prosecutor angel.

Also, if Satan were to be seen as an adversary of G-d, how would it make sense that in 2 Samuel 24:1 G-d incites David to count Israel; whereas in 1 Chronicles 21:1, which is describing the same event, Satan incites David to count Israel.

Furthermore, the idea of someone being possessed is completely antithetical to the Hebrew Bible. The Hebrew Bible maintains that each person has responsibility for his own actions such as in Ezekiel 18 and other places.

As for why it mentions the King of Tyre's being in the garden of Eden and as a shielding cherub, that is a metaphor. The King of Tyre was very successful as if he was in the garden of Eden, and as if he was a shielding cherub, but he sinned and became arrogant, so G-d is going to punish him.

Comment: The King of Tyre was such an important figure in the world that Satan himself decided to possess him,and Ezekiel was sent to directly address Satan with a message from God!!

Answer (score 0):

Ezekiel 28:5-19 outlines the consequences of **Haughty** (גָּבַ֚הּ) behavior caused by abundant wisdom & wealth.

**By reminding the Prince of Tyre (Tsor, צֹ֜ר) about a haughty Keruv (כְּר֔וּב) cast from the Garden of Eden [possibly alluding to Ha-Satan or Azazel], the prophet Yechezkel (Ezekiel) foreshadows the demise of angels & humans who "become prideful" (וַיִּגְבַּ֥הּ).**

**Haughty behavior of the Prince of Tyre**

> Ezekiel 28:5 [MT]
> " With your great wisdom in your commerce did you increase your wealth, that your heart **became haughty** with your wealth? " (בְּרֹ֧ב חָכְמָֽתְךָ֛ בִּרְכֻלָּֽתְךָ֖ הִרְבִּ֣יתָ חֵילֶ֑ךָ וַיִּגְבַּ֥הּ לְבָבְךָ֖ בְּחֵילֶֽךָ )

**Haughty behavior of Keruv in Eden**

> Ezekiel 28:17 [MT]
> " Your heart became **haughty** because of your beauty; you destroyed your wisdom with your brightness; I have cast you upon the ground; I have set you before kings to gaze upon you. " (גָּבַ֚הּ לִבְּךָ֙ בְּיָפְיֶ֔ךָ שִׁחַ֥תָּ חָכְמָֽתְךָ֖ עַל־יִפְעָתֶ֑ךָ עַל־אֶ֣רֶץ הִשְׁלַכְתִּ֗יךָ לִפְנֵ֧י מְלָכִ֛ים נְתַתִּ֖יךָ לְרַ֥אֲוָה בָֽךְ)

**Why would readers presume the Keruv in [Ezekiel 28] refers to Ha-Satan?**

- Ezekiel 28:13 [MT] describes beautiful Keruv angel from the Garden of Eden.

> "In Eden, the garden of God you were; every precious stone was [set in] your covering; ruby, topaz, diamond, chrysolite, onyx, and jasper, sapphire, carbuncle, and crystal and gold; the work of your drums and your orifices is in you; on the day of your creation they were established." (בְּעֵ֨דֶן גַּן־אֱלֹהִ֜ים הָיִ֗יתָ כָּל־אֶ֨בֶן יְקָרָ֚ה מְסֻכָתֶ֙ךָ֙ אֹ֣דֶם פִּטְדָ֞ה וְיַֽהֲלֹ֗ם תַּרְשִׁ֥ישׁ שֹׁ֙הַם֙ וְיָ֣שְׁפֵ֔ה סַפִּ֣יר נֹ֔פֶךְ וּבָֽרְקַ֖ת וְזָהָ֑ב מְלֶ֨אכֶת תֻּפֶּ֚יךָ וּנְקָבֶ֙יךָ֙ בָּ֔ךְ בְּי֥וֹם הִבָּֽרַאֲךָ֖ כּוֹנָֽנוּ)

- Ezekiel 28:15-17 [MT] elaborates that this speceific Keruv angel from the Garden of Eden was perfect but **became haughty** from abundant wealth & wisdom.

> Ezekiel 28:15 [MT] : "You were perfect in your ways from the day you were created until wrongdoing was found in you." (תָּמִ֚ים אַתָּה֙ בִּדְרָכֶ֔יךָ מִיּ֖וֹם הִבָּֽרְאָ֑ךְ עַד־נִמְצָ֥א עַוְלָ֖תָה בָּֽךְ )

> Ezekiel 28:16 [MT] : "Because of the multitude of your commerce, they filled you with violence and you sinned, and I shall cast you as profane from the mountain of God, and I shall destroy you, O covering Keruv, from among the stones of fire." (בְּרֹ֣ב רְכֻלָּֽתְךָ֗ מָל֧וּ תֽוֹכְךָ֛ חָמָ֖ס וַתֶּֽחֱטָ֑א וָֽאֲחַלֶּלְךָ֩ מֵהַ֨ר אֱלֹהִ֚ים וָֽאַבֶּדְךָ֙ כְּר֣וּב הַסּוֹכֵ֔ךְ מִתּ֖וֹךְ אַבְנֵי־אֵֽשׁ )

> Ezekiel 28:17 [MT]
> " Your heart became **haughty** because of your beauty; you destroyed your wisdom with your brightness; I have cast you upon the ground; I have set you before kings to gaze upon you. " (גָּבַ֚הּ לִבְּךָ֙ בְּיָפְיֶ֔ךָ שִׁחַ֥תָּ חָכְמָֽתְךָ֖ עַל־יִפְעָתֶ֑ךָ עַל־אֶ֣רֶץ הִשְׁלַכְתִּ֗יךָ לִפְנֵ֧י מְלָכִ֛ים נְתַתִּ֖יךָ לְרַ֥אֲוָה בָֽךְ)

- Who is this haughty Keruv from the Garden of Eden?

**Has the Tanakh ever mentioned a Keruv angel from the Garden Eden that claimed to have the wisdom of God?** - Perhaps Ezekiel 28:15-17 references [Genesis 3].

> Genesis 3:4 [MT] : "And the-serpent said to the woman, "You will surely not die." (וַיֹּ֥אמֶר הַנָּחָ֖שׁ אֶל־הָֽאִשָּׁ֑ה לֹא־מ֖וֹת תְּמֻתֽוּן )

> Genesis 3:5 [MT] : "For God knows that on the day that you eat thereof, your eyes will be opened, and you will be like angels, knowing good and evil." (כִּ֚י יֹדֵ֣עַ אֱלֹהִ֔ים כִּ֗י בְּיוֹם֙ אֲכָלְכֶ֣ם מִמֶּ֔נּוּ וְנִפְקְח֖וּ עֵֽינֵיכֶ֑ם וִֽהְיִיתֶם֙ כֵּֽאלֹהִ֔ים יֹֽדְעֵ֖י ט֥וֹב וָרָֽע)

**Was the-Serpent ( Ha-Nachash, הַנָּחָ֖שׁ ) an angel ?**

- In Bereishit (Genesis) 3, the author Moshe (Moses) did not state that the-Serpent (Ha-Nachash) was the-Adversary angel (Ha-Satan).
- In Ezekiel 28, the prophet Yechezkel does not explicitly state the Keruv of Eden was the-Adversary angel Ha-Satan.

**Since Genesis 3 [MT] does not explicitly associate Ha-Satan with the Serpent who hoards the Tree of Knowledge of Good & Evil, which canonical/non-canonical book of the Bible helps make the connection that the haughty Keruv of Eden from [Ezekiel 28] with an abundantly wise & lawless Keruv ?**

- The Book of Enoch attempts to associate with the fallen Keruv named "Azazel" with the haughty Keruv of [Ezekiel 28] who taught mankind wisdom.
- [Enoch 9:1] "And then Michael, Uriel, Raphael, and Gabriel looked down from heaven and saw much blood being shed upon the earth, and all lawlessness being wrought upon the earth."
- [Enoch 9:6] "Thou seest what Azâzêl hath done, who hath taught all unrighteousness on earth and revealed the eternal secrets which were (preserved) in heaven, which men were striving to learn."

**Perhaps the prophet Yechezkel is associating the haughty Prince of Tyre with the fallen Keruv Azazel, based on the book of Enoch.**

Comment: @claytographics. The answer to your question " Was the-Serpent ( Ha-Nachash, הַנָּחָ֖שׁ ) an angel ?"  may be drawn out by the following questions. Who used the literal serpent in Eden as his means of communicating with the woman? The Bible’s first prophecy (Ge 3:15) states that the ‘seed of the woman,’ after himself suffering a bruising of the heel, will bruise the serpent’s head. Who is the serpent and who is the seed of the woman in this prophecy?

Comment: The seed of the serpent is clearly future snakes. The seed of the woman is clearly future men. As they can attack us on the heel because they are lower on the ground, and we can stomp on their heads as we are higher off the ground. Also the most instinctual fear for humans is a fear of snakes yet again proving the Bible's point.